# tf.train.batch() with my own data? and an issue on training the model

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, dataset

I am trying to understand about why I can't train my network model but I couldn't. I will be very appreciated if you could help me to solve this issue.

---

I already read my image data (600), resized (14x14) and normalize it. Also, I created my onehot_encoding in my code.

My "img_data" variable in the code has normalized 600 images (14x14 size of each image) and "labels_training" variable has 600 (each label has 10 binary number) labeled onehot_encoding. I am expecting that tf.train.batch() should return (50, 196) and (50,10) but it returns:

Tensor("batch_31:0", shape=(50, 600, 196), dtype=float32) for X_truth
Tensor("batch_31:1", shape=(50, 600, 10), dtype=float32) for X_label

Why does tf.train.batch() function returns 3 values (50, 600, 196) and (50, 600, 10)?

Also, when I try .eval() for X_truth and X_label, it never ends.

```
epochs = 12
print("Start to train")
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
for _ in range(1000):
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
    for i in range(epochs):
        print("Epoch ", i)
        X_truth, X_label = tf.train.batch([img_data, labels_training],batch_size=50) 
        x_input=X_truth.eval()
        y_input=X_label.eval()
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: x_input, y_: y_input})
```

Many many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Tensorflow documentation
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch

> If enqueue_many is False, tensors is assumed to represent a single example. An input tensor with shape [x, y, z] will be output as a tensor with shape [batch_size, x, y, z].

`enqueue_many` is False by default

Comment: many many thanks and I got it now and the problem has been solved. Also, when I try .eval() for X_truth and X_label, it never ends. Could you please provide a solution for it?

Comment: @Esriak You need to move the `tf.train.batch` and  `tf.queue_runners` outside the loop take a look here it might help you http://ischlag.github.io/2016/06/19/tensorflow-input-pipeline-example/

Comment: thank you so much for your help. It was great helpful to solve my issues and my code is working without any problem now. I want to ask one final question. I moved tf.train.batch and tf.queue_runners outside the loop but howcome I can epoch more than 1 time in the same iteration? Many Thanks Mohamed. Very appreciated.

Comment: @Esriak Calling .eval will automatically load the next batch it should reset if all batches are done and will load the first batch again

Comment: Thank you so much.